# Lambda versioning - does not trigger specific version via SQS

Tags: function, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have SQS that triggers the lambda function.

Lambda function has version 3 ( with alias prod ) .

When I set it to any version other than LATEST, it does not get triggered.

Any ideas why? Can SQS only trigger latest lambda function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can define `version` when using Function `ARN`.

Example :

1.`helloword` with version `1`

```
arn:aws:lambda:aws-region:acct-id:function:helloworld:1
```

reference Link: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases-permissions.html)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that we can define SQS relationship for a Lambda function from the Lambda console it self. Select tjhe  version/alias, and then go to designer, and you can see SQS, SNS etc. where in u can put in the ARN of the SQS with the :1 etc or add :PROD for alias

Answer (score 0):

I found that if multiple versions of a function are triggered by the same queue, there's some sort of a race and different versions may get triggered.

So, it seems, you should be careful to use different queues or remove the trigger relationship from versions you're no longer actively using/testing with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be expected to have race conditions if multiple versions of the function are attached to the same queue. Lambda does not provide fan-out features on SQS integrations as of now.

With that being said, let's say we have three versions that use the same queue as the event source. Then overall there is a 33.33% chance that for any of the three versions to be invoked for any messages sent. This is simply because when Lambda polls those queues, the messages are agnostic to functions, and it all depends on which function is lucky at the very moment.

As for the concern in this original post - if you only hooked the `$LATEST` with a queue, then only `$LATEST` will be invoked; if you want any other function versions to be invoked, you will need to create new event source mappings for each of the version to be invoked. On top of that, the event source queue can be the same for all versions, or it can be different, based on your use case.

Hope this helps.